# Save a struct into a file then read it in the same program

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have this struct which I stack with information, I'm doing that via pointers, after doing that I'm saving all the info into a file named `person.txt` and then read it in the same program.
The problems I'm having are:

1. I can display the final result correctly, but, the `person.txt` file doesn't have any meaningful text in it, it's just a bunch of unknown symbols for me (I guess it's automatically saved in bit, but I don't know why it does that).
2. After inserting the info and the `.txt` file is created and the result is displayed, after closing the program, when trying to use only the code to read the file (meaning I make a `commentary` out of the code I won't need), it displays me something else, totally different of what I initially introduced.

Heres the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct eu
{
    char name[30];
    int age,weight, number;
};

int main()
{
    struct eu *Eu1, euptr;
    Eu1 = &euptr;

    printf("Name & Surname:");
    scanf("%[^\n]", Eu1->name);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Age:");
    scanf("%d", &Eu1->age);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Weigt(kg):");
    scanf("%d", &Eu1->weight);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Telephone number:");
    scanf("%d", &Eu1->number);
    printf("\n\nDisplay: ");

    FILE *outinfo;
    outinfo = fopen("person.txt", "a");

    if (outinfo == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nSomething went wrong!\n");
    }

    fwrite(&Eu1, sizeof(struct eu),1,outinfo);

    fclose(outinfo);

    outinfo = fopen("person.txt", "r");

    while(fread(&Eu1, sizeof(struct eu), 1, outinfo))
        printf ("\n Name:%s\n Age:%d\n Weight:%d\n Tel. Number:%d\n ", Eu1->name, Eu1->age, Eu1->weight, Eu1->number );

    fclose (outinfo);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you commented out some required code. Without knowing what you are doing, we cannot tell what is causing issue 2.

Comment: Any data written with `fwrite` is saved as binary dump of memory content. If you expect readable numbers in text format, you must use `fprintf` and friends to save each member separately.

Comment: Two things I don't like that not the use of parentheses such as `&(Eu1->weight)` and `struct eu *Eu1, euptr;`. The latter is too confusing because i don't get whether `*euptr` or `euptr`. **kid code**. And Jonathan Leffler always says that always use and get return values of functions if there is. For example, what if 'fwrite bumps out' ?

Comment: `fwrite` writes _raw bytes_, which aren't necessarily human-readable. If you want the file to contain "meaningful text", you'll need to write code to serialize `struct eu`s the way you want

Comment: `fwrite(&Eu1, ...)` should be `fwrite(Eu1, ...)`, because `Eu1` is already a pointer. Or get rid of `Eu1` and just use `euptr` (but rename it, as it is not a pointer)

Comment: Whey did you name your pointer `Eu1`, and the object `euptr`?  I would expect the variable named `euptr` to be a pointer, not the other way around.

Comment: If you're going to use `scanf`, you should be more careful.  eg, instead of `"%[^\n]"`, use `"%29[^\n]"` to prevent buffer overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you've messed the pointers. It is ok to save whole struct into the file, here is correctly working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct eu
{
    char name[30];
    int age,weight, number;
};

int main()
{
    struct eu eu1, *euptr;
    euptr = &eu1;


    printf("Name & Surname:");
    scanf("%[^\n]", euptr->name);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Age:");
    scanf("%d", &euptr->age);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Weigt(kg):");
    scanf("%d", &euptr->weight);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Telephone number:");
    scanf("%d", &euptr->number);
    printf("\n\nDisplay: ");

    FILE *outinfo;
    outinfo = fopen("person.txt", "a");

    if (outinfo == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nSomething went wrong!\n");
    }

    fwrite(euptr, sizeof(struct eu), 1, outinfo);
    fclose(outinfo);

    outinfo = fopen("person.txt", "r");
    while(fread(&eu1, sizeof(struct eu), 1, outinfo))
        printf ("\n Name:%s\n Age:%d\n Weight:%d\n Tel. Number:%d\n ", euptr->name, euptr->age, euptr->weight, euptr->number );

    fclose (outinfo);
    return 0;
}
```

I've swapped `eu1` & `euptr` variables for more logical naming.

Comment: Don't write `Something went wrong`.  That is a useless error message.  Try `perror("person.txt")`

Comment: Agree, but I've just used @Vlad's code to correct pointers.

Comment: Thank you, now I've understood my mistake, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`fwrite` will write the raw data you have given it, for the number of bytes you have specified. You are able to write this struct and read it back which is exactly what you are trying to do, all is working as intended. "Normal" text files with words use a particular encoding (usually ascii or unicode), and you need to use that encoding if you want it to be readable.

If you wanted this to be human readable, you would need to specify a format. A very simple one would be CSV (comma separated values).

So you might do something like

```
fprintf(outinfo, "%s,%d,%d,%d", Eu1.name, Eu1.age, Eu1.weight, Eu1.number);
//...
fseek(outinfo,0,SEEK_SET);// move to beginning of file
fscanf(outinfo, "%s,%d,%d,%d", &Eu2.name, &Eu2.age, &Eu2.weight, &Eu2.number);
```

this doesn't involve any error checking, and would need to be changed if your struct format changed, but would allow the file to be human readable if that was a requirement for you.